# Is there a way to add a marker to the current position of the camera in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: google-earth

I'm trying to find exact locations of photographs I've taken years ago. I usually have an idea of the rough location, and - whenever they feature big landmarks - I use Google Earth to find the exact position by positioning the camera.
However, I cannot figure out an easy way to add a marker directly on the spot where I carefully positioned the viewpoint. Is there an easy way to do so?

[image: Camera positioned using photograph as reference]

Comment: Might be better asked on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks, but this is about Google Earth Pro, the desktop software.